# Can I make my angular-ui-router stateProvider definition shorter?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-ui-router, which is generally great, but my code to define the stateProvider is becoming quite repetitive, e.g.

```
.state('home', {
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: "home.html"
})
.state('products', {
  url: "/products",
  templateUrl: "products.html"
})
.state('suppliers', {
  url: "/suppliers",
  templateUrl: "suppliers.html"
})
```

Is there some way to tell it that every state has a URL and template that matches the state name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Write a function.**

```
var myState = function($stateProvider, name) {
    $stateProvider.state(name, {
        url: '/' + name,
        templateUrl: name + '.html'
    })
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
myState($stateProvider, 'home');
myState($stateProvider, 'products');
myState($stateProvider, 'suppliers');
```

If you like you can also extend the `$stateProvider` object:

```
$stateProvider.myState = function(name) {
    return this.state(name, {
        url: '/' + name,
        templateUrl: name + '.html'
    })
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .myState('home')
    .myState('products')
    .myState('suppliers');
```

Comment: Works a treat! Although $stateProvider.prototype.myState caused "TypeError: Cannot set property 'parentState' of undefined" (in Chrome) but just doing $stateProvider.myState works fine. Not sure why that is. Regardless, your approach is very neat and saves lots of code :-)

Comment: The `prototype` was my bad. Thanks for pointing that out, i fixed my post. Glad it helped!